# Profiling a method in C# to know how long does it take to run

Tags: c#, visual-studio, visual-studio-2010, mono, profiling

I need to get a timing report to know how long does it take to run a C# method in a class. 
I think about using `profiler` to do that.

The input is the name of a method in a class, the output is

1. What method/class calls this method.
2. The amount of time to run the method.

What tools/commercial products are available for that for Visual Studio 2010 and Mono?

Comment: In the higher end versions of VS 2010 you have an integrated Profiler, no need for a commercial product besides that.

Comment: possible duplicate of [How do I improve performance of winforms application in Mono?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/614478/how-do-i-improve-performance-of-winforms-application-in-mono)

Comment: Now a duplicate of the same question you've asked again.  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6244549/hooking-up-net-method-for-profiling-purposes

Comment: @Will A : I intentionally made two questions, the other question is about hooking method to profile something (you can see the comment 'or (not) running the profiler' to specify this, this question is about using profiler to do the same thing. – prosseek 5 secs ago edit

Comment: *"The amount of time to run the method. "* - System.Diagnostics.Stopwatch.

Comment: Wall-clock or CPU time? Inclusive time or exclusive? Percent, or average & call count?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Another opensource profiler is slimtune http://code.google.com/p/slimtune/

Alternatively you can create your own profiler using COM and the ICorProfilerCallback interfaces, but I would do this if you wanted a very customized profiler gathering.

Comment: +1 for mentioning the ICorProfilerCallback interface -- neat!

Answer (score 4):

You could use:

- [CLR Profiler](http://www.microsoft.com/downloads/en/details.aspx?FamilyID=be2d842b-fdce-4600-8d32-a3cf74fda5e1) (free)
- [Red Gate ANTS Performance Profiler](http://www.red-gate.com/products/dotnet-development/ants-performance-profiler/) ($400)

Both will provide you with call graphs and method timings.  The Red Gate tool is nice and has a 14 day trial.  It also provides line level timings, which I'm not sure if the free CLR Profiler tool will do for you.

Answer (score 1):

To add to Michaels answer, there's also:

[DotTrace](http://www.jetbrains.com/profiler/) ($400)

I personally perfer it over the Red Gate profiler.